# Client Autherification with Certificate

Tags: vba, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to connect to server with certificate based Autherification. Certificate is installed on Win10.

My code is:

```
    Dim request As Object
    request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    request.SetClientCertificate("Local Computer\Personal\Certificates\friently_cert_name")

    Dim rest_request As String = "SOAP"

    request.Open("GET", "<URL>")
    request.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*")
    request.SetRequestHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")

    request.Send(rest_request)
```

It lead to error: Value doesn't fall with expected range

After I tried to use: 
`request.SetClientCertificate("friently_cert_name")`

It was led to issue:  A certificate is required to complete client authentication

Could advise how to resolve an issue?

Comment: you don't need the brackets by the way.

Comment: by which way ? and were I don't need a bracket ?

Comment: you only need () here request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1") I believe.

Comment: Can we talk directly ? my skype is pavel.zimahorau

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pYthvL6B

Comment: still the same issue: A certificate is required to complete client authentication

Comment: I'm just fixing the other areas of your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187361/discussion-between-pavel-zimogorov-and-qharr).

Comment: did you guys manage to resolve the issue, find that I need to do something along these lines, but what exactly is still a mystery.HttpReq.SetClientCertificate (certificate_content)